# Unidentified reflection in renders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm building an elevator scene using Cycles. The interior of the elevator is currently all glossy gray materials with 9 small lights on the top and an extra shiny bar on one wall. The floor is an image texture.

[image: mcdonals][image: No roghtnes]

Herein lies the problem. Most renders made of this elevator show a light gray section on the back wall and kind of on the side walls of the elevator. This doesn't seem to be anything in the file and it's general existence bothers me to no end. Is there any way to either eradicate it or just make it not appear?

Comment: Can you make a quick render with 0 roghtnes

Comment: @AlfonsMarklén Yeah, here you go. [link](http://imgur.com/a/B4plG)

Comment: It do feel like it is the standard background color. Is the problem that it isn't a object there or is it that it's the wrong object.

Comment: @AlfonsMarklén I don't think it's the background color. Made the world color blue and it didn't affect the anomaly. I think it may be the light I have outside of the elevator, considering that the anomaly disappears when the elevator doors are closed. I forgot to mention those.

Comment: Anyway, I made it so the light doesn't show up on glossy textures. That seems to have solved it.